# Transition from Launchpad to application sets focus on SearchField

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

we have the problem that a transition from the SAP Fiori Launchpad into our application sets the focus on the SearchField of the Master view.

[image: UI5 SearchField]

It's a problem, because on mobile devices it triggers the activation of the keyboard which blocks the list view entries.

Any idea how to prevent that behaviour?

Directly entering the application is not creating this problem.

It's also happening in another Master/Detail application we created.

Across Android and iOS devices, replicated on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Kind regards,

Michael

Comment: Can you provide the code which triggers the transition from the Launchpad to your Application?

Comment: Hi Tim. The Launchpad is set up with the Launchpad Designer and a huge pack of SAP transactions, in a very complex process. How SAP is making the connections between a click on a Launchpad tile and the application is completely out of my hands. Therefore I can't provide any code, it's a SAP thing. But I was told that the sapui5 tag would be the official SAP dev channel, hence I hope they see my question.

Comment: I've not seen the above mentioned behavior being the developer of many master-detail pattern apps. What's the SAPUI5 version? And the name of SAP delivered app?

Comment: UI5 version is 1.26.9 and I'm talking about the SAP Fiori Launchpad http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/f9/51b50a07ce41deb08ced62711fe8b5/frameset.htm

Comment: @Deftoned I wanted to know the app in which Search Box is getting focused.. Something like Leave Request/Approval/Sales Order. Application Name

Comment: @SunilBN It's our own application, based on an older Sales Order example.

Comment: I'm redirecting future readers to a newer Q&A. Unlike in the past, the FLP should by now set the focus to the shell header title. If not, the only option is to explicitly set the focus somewhere else in the application which the linked Q&A explains how.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but we had the same problem. Using `onAfterRendering` does work only once because that lifecycle hook gets only called once. To solve the issue do the following:

```
onInit: function () {
    // onAfterShow hook gets called every time the view is shown
    this.getView().addEventDelegate({onAfterShow: this._afterShow}, this);
},

_afterShow: function () {
    jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
        jQuery('input').blur();
    });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround (the easiest solution I could Find as of now)
since I couldn't reproduce your issue :(

`onDataLoaded()` or in `onAfterRedering()` methods

//basically set the focus on something like this.. OR just create any SAPUI5 element and `setVisible(false)` and set the `focus()`

```
this.getList().focus();
```

UPDATE: Catch hold of search in `getHeaderFooterOptions()`

```
getHeaderFooterOptions: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var objHdrFtr = {
       //sI18NMasterTitle: "YOUR_TITLE",
        onRefresh: function (searchField, fnRefreshCompleted) {
            _this._searchField = searchField;
        }
    };
    return objHdrFtr;
}
```

then

```
onAfterRendering(){
 if(this._searchField){
 this._searchField.onAfterRendering = function() {
            jQuery(this.getDomRef()).focusout()
        };
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works or not!
I will delete the answer.